# Xamarin IOS Facebook SDK LoginButton

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin, sdk, xamarin.ios

Im new to Xamarin and IOS development and dont understand why I get this following error:

But first some Information:

Im using this SDK:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios

and creating my LoginButtin in my ViewController in ViewDidLoad like this:

```
loginButton = new LoginButton(new CGRect(48, 0, 218, 46))
            {
                LoginBehavior = LoginBehavior.Native,
                ReadPermissions = readPermissions.ToArray()
            };
            View.AddSubview(button);
```

But in my Storyboard I get this error message:

[image]

Edit: my ViewController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UIKit;

namespace FacebookLogin
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        List<string> readPermissions = new List<string> { "public_profile" };
        LoginButton loginButton;

        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            loginButton = new LoginButton(new CGRect(48, 0, 218, 46))
            {
                LoginBehavior = LoginBehavior.Native,
                ReadPermissions = readPermissions.ToArray()
            };
            View.AddSubview(button);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you create loginButton? On stroyboard or code behind?

Comment: In ViewController.cs (fresh Single View App), I tought this is code behind

Comment: Please attach the whole code in your ViewController.

Comment: ok, edit my original post but there is nothing special, just the same as shown here: https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios

Comment: Im 100% sure, like I said, its a fresh project, just added the facebook dll to References (4.27.1)

Comment: Does it something to do with a Simulator?

Comment: It won't Work on Simulator. You need to have a Apple device(iPad/iPhone)! It won't run on simulator

Comment: Im grateful for any notice but could you explain why this wont work on simulator.

Comment: Works fine on simulator as of this comment

Comment: Yes you are right. I don’t know why but it’s start working after I created a brand new project and copy paste my code

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to follow the instructions found on the [getting started](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebookios) page. I see an empty component in your solution explorer but just in case, make sure that you installed Xamarin.Facebook.iOS 4.27.1 with nugget. Of course, you also need to set up your [facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/), login, and configure the iOS portion (like setting the BundleID).

Don't create the button in the controller. What you can do is use the storyBoard designer to drop in a regular button. Then, in the properties window click on Class and it should open a dropdown menu. In the selection you should see FBSDKLoginButton, select that class. Give it a name like btnFacebook.

In the codebehind for your controller it will look like this:

```
string[] readPermissions = { "public_profile" };

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
  base.ViewDidLoad();
  btn.LoginBehavior = LoginBehavior.Native;
  btnFacebook.ReadPermissions = readPermissions;
  // Handle actions once the user is logged in
  btnFacebook.Completed += LoginView_Completed;
  // Handle actions once the user is logged out
  btnFacebook.LoggedOut += LoginView_LoggedOut;
}

private void LoginView_Completed(object sender, LoginButtonCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Error != null)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (e.Result.IsCancelled)
  {
    return;
  }
}

private void LoginView_LoggedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

For good measure, clean solution and recompile. The login button won't appear as a facebook login button in your designer but on runtime it will.

As for your error, I don't see anything in your designer so it's curious that it's giving you an error like that. Open the Document Outline (View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline) and see if there's any invisible garbage (elements that aren't being rendered) that has to be deleted.

Comment: I have no invisible elements (just View, Exit, Top Layout Guide, Bottom Layout Guide)

    Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (15.5.0)

    Connected to remote Mac with Sierra (10.12.6), with Xamarin.IOS 11.4   (IOS 9,10,11)

    Latest Mono Framework (MDK 5.3.1.7)

What I allready tried:

    Clean, rebuilt (about 1000x)

    Add Facebook reference manually + NuGet

    Different releases of the SDK

    Info.plist -> Version, Build, Deployment Target: 10.0

    Supported Architectures: i386 + x86_64

Default settings for the rest

What do you mean by empty component?

Answer (score 1):

First Of All! You're on the right Way To solve your issue
and Secondly, I would Suggest you that you have created a controller in the above image you need to create a View Controller File and then add a Login Screen Like a Username named Textbox Then a Password named Textbox and A login Button and then View Controller will automatically created once you save the view And Then Finally, You Save the view Controller By Adding the Following Code

```
partial void login_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(clientId: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID", scope: "", authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"), redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));
        auth.Completed += Auth_Completed;
        var ui = auth.GetUI();
        PresentViewController(ui, true, null);

    }

    private async void Auth_Completed(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            var request = new OAuth2Request("POST", new Uri("YOUR Location Where You want to reach After Login"), null, e.Account);

            //fb://profile/<id> For opening in Facebook App.


        }
        DismissViewController(true, null);
    }
```

You See the Above Code And If you Want to Open the Facebook Link In Facebook Application Just Replace URL with

```
fb://profile/<id>
```

Comment: I dont get it, sorry. I allready have a ViewController.cs, why should I add a second one? I think I dont need OAuth2Authenticator, because LoginButton should handle this automatically for me, but I am insecure about that.

Comment: No Worries! Completely Fine. You can Use NSURL instead of OAuth2Authenticator
and For ViewController.cs I meant to say in your ViewController File Not to Create it again.

Comment: Ok thanks but I think you try to show me alternate ways but I have a problem with this specific sdk LoginButton.